# Selecting Line of Pandas DataFrame by a String Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of the form:

[image]

Where "it", "their" and "charact" are the indexes. How can I select a value based on the index? When I try the following:

```
corpus_df.iloc['it',1]
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `corpus_df.loc['it'][1]` instead

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is: `corpus_df.loc['it', 1]`

There are two different properties: **loc** and **iloc**
**iloc** is used for integer position based indexing.
**loc** is used for label based indexing, therefore you can use it with string index value.

Comment: Please add correct formatting for code. See [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
corpus_df[corpus_df.index == 'it']
```

I found this suited in case of (e.g.) GeoDataFrames, where filtering for index  via `loc`-indexer yields the geometry directly, which cannot be plotted, e.g. this works:

```py
shapes[shapes.index == "nevada"].plot()
```

This does not work:

```py
shapes.loc["nevada"].plot()
> TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```